# Gmail API Android `Quickstart` hits a brick wall

Tags: android, api, google-oauth

The [google demo](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) makes a single API request. I have tried to use this code as the basis for a more real world scenario (multiple different API calls) but keep hitting a brick wall. The demo's structure makes it very difficult.

Consider the code that makes the API request:

```
private void getResultsFromApi() {
    if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        acquireGooglePlayServices();
    } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
        mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
    } else {
        new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
    }
}
```

`getResultsFromApi()` does a lot of auth stuff before the API request. Should this be done before every API request??

`getResultsFromApi()` may start an activity (in chooseAccount())which means that the `onActivityResult()` will (re)call `getResultsFromApi()` in order to eventually get to the API request.

In fact there are actually 5 calls to `getResultsFromApi()` in the code which together achieve the auth for the single API request!! It may be necessary but it ends up being spaghetti.

This makes the demo impossible to generalize in its current form. Say I want a 2nd button making some other API request. Cant be done without a major rewrite

Can anyone suggest how I can reorganise the demo code in order to make it useable in the real world?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getResultsFromApi does not do "a lot of stuff" it just checks that everything is done correctly as said in the demo project :

> Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
>         satisfied

If a condition is not satisfied another function will be called to solve this, like to select an account. Then getResultsFromApi will be called again to finish that call that you started with not all the preconditions satisfied.

You are not force to do all the checks, but if a precondition is not satisfied your call will fail.